# TurboTax how to enter "Self-employed health insurance deduction" (1040 line 29) for my income from S-corp K-1?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction

1040 line 7 = $135K  wages an employer not related to my S-corp.
1040 line 17 = $90 from my S-corp K-1.

1040 line 29: "Self-employed health insurance deduction"  Can I enter my $9300 health insur premium

Comment: If you did, it would show a $9210 loss from the S corp. If you show losses year after year, you are not in business, and can't take losses.

Comment: Is your health insurance through your employer, or do you get it on your own?

Comment: Did you have any salary (besides the $90 profit) from your S-corp?

Comment: (@JoeTaxpayer) according to [the instructions for 1040 line 29](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi/ar01.html#d0e5415) (at page 32 in the PDF) your deduction is the _smaller_ of the premium paid (excluding months eligible for an employer plan) and 'your net profit* and any other earned income** from the business' (see original for notes).

Comment: Did you take out any dividends from the S-corp in 2016?